# Unable to send matplotlib picture using discord.py

Tags: python, matplotlib, discord, discord.py

I am trying to send a graph I made using matplotlib into a discord chat using discord.py. I am able to create the figure, but I am unsure how to send the file itself to discord.

Here is the picture that shows up when I run this code:

[image]

Here is my code for this:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np 
import asyncio
import discord
import os
import time
import io

async def create_score_bargraph(ctx, percentage_list, votes_list):   
    x_labels = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10']

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])
    ax.bar(x_labels, votes_list)
    plt.show()

    filename =  "test.png"
    image = discord.File(filename=filename)
    plt.savefig(filename)

    await ctx.send(file = image)

    plt.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save the image before making the `discord.File` and you should not pass the file name as the filename keyword argument, using instead the fp (file path) positional argument.

Substitute this chunk of code:

```py
filename =  "test.png"
image = discord.File(filename=filename)
plt.savefig(filename)
```

With this:

```py
filename =  "test.png"
plt.savefig(filename)
image = discord.File(filename)
```

Also, quick suggestion, if you make a question be sure to say when there's an error, because in this case, not passing the fp value for the discord.File class will raise an error.

Comment: I did that, and that didn't work, although it did create a file called "test.png" that had the plot

Comment: @ShitijGovil tested it out and found the error, could've just told me there was an error tho. I edited the answer accordingly, so now it should work just fine.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it worked! However, I was not able to see any errors from my side(I am using VSCode). What are you using such that you are able to see those errors? Thanks for all the help

Comment: I use PyCharm, although whenever you execute python scripts, the errors should show up on the console.(unless they're being caught by a try/except)

Comment: Thank you so much, I forgot that I had my program just pass the exception if there was an error